# how to access same cookies in webview with different process?

Tags: cookies, webview, google-chrome-app

Iam using webview tag dynamically to load webpage . my requirement is to load webpage in different process. so if i give partition = "myId"+dyanmicval it creates different proccess with different session(cookies) storage. if i give partition = "persist:commonId" it shares same session storage but it's not creating seperate process. 
I need to create different process for each webview tag with same session storage(cookies). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be impossible.

Webviews with the same persistent partition will share the process, and you can't extract the cookie store for reuse.